# Statistical analysis of disappearing eagles

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, missing-data

[image: Summary of tag fate by tag model]

Satellite tagged eagles are going missing in Scotland, and the table above shows the tag fate by tag model. I am particularly interested in those tags that are "Stopped - no malfunction", because it is possible that these birds are also being killed and the bodies and tags are being disposed of.

I have seen it stated that this table and this table alone is evidence that ["Even with the remotest statistical analysis it is clear that there are relationships between "Stopped - No Malfunction" and the type of tag used"](http://davidadamsketchbook.blogspot.co.uk/2018/03/review-of-snh-report-on-satellite.html) So my question is, can this statement be backed up?

```
42/135  (31%) tags stopped for all types 
 8/17   (47%) tags stopped for 80NS     
29/77   (38%) tags stopped for 70GPS    
 3/22   (14%) tags stopped for 105GPS   
 2/13   (15%) tags stopped for 70GSM    
 0/6     (0%) tags stopped for 95BTOGSM
```

So I guess that the statement is true if the 80NS failure rate of 47% is significantly worse than global average of 31%.  And it would not be true if the probability of getting 8 failures in a random sample of 17 tags out of the 135 was actually quite high. More abstractly, if there were 42 black balls and 93 white balls in a bag and I picked out 17 at random, what is the probability I'd pick 8 black ones and 9 white ones?

I can work out the probability of the first 8 being black as (42/135) * (41/134) etc. but I'm stuck trying to work out the likelihood of any 8 of the 17 being black

---

**EDIT:** The satellite tags were attached to birds over a 13 year period, 2004 to 2016. This table shows 131 tags rather than 135. 4 tags were excluded because they could not ascertain the precise deployment location of four early tags.

[image: Tag type by tag year]

Here is another table from the [report](http://www.snh.org.uk/pdfs/publications/commissioned_reports/982.pdf) that shows some data about the life of the 70GPS/70GSM tags:

[image: Stopped no malfunction tag duration of operation]

Comment: Colin, your question lacks a key variable: time since the tag was applied. It's also possible other variables might be confounded with tag model: for instance, maybe different models are used on different species, or birds of different sizes, or some are older and some younger.  Assuming, then, that this is a real problem of genuine concern, consider including such data in your analysis.

Comment: @whuber I've added time data. Yes, there are many variables, but I was interested in what this table in isolation can tell us, and specifically the "stopped - no malfunction" row. FYI, nests were visited to fit transmitters to nestlings when the chicks were between approximately 50 - 70 days old, based on plumage. Golden eagles weighed between 3.4 and 5.0 kg at time of tagging. The full report is here, if you're interested: http://www.snh.org.uk/pdfs/publications/commissioned_reports/982.pdf

Comment: @Antoine I can see why you thought it was homework, but I'm afraid I'm  too old now for homework. This is a real world issue that I'm interested in. Partly because I'm interested in statistics and the misuse of statistics, and partly because I don't like raptor persecution. It's my first post in the statistics area of stack exchange so if it's inappropriate, I apologise

Comment: Not at all inappropriate!  We just get a lot of people who paste their homework and seem to expect us to answer it for them, so there's some sensitivity around that.  But as a REAL question, this is definitely on topic.

Comment: If you don't mind, leave the time table in. It adds interesting challenges to the question. Do you know what years the tags were lost?  Ideally, we could connect the corresponding attachment, fate, & type for every tag.

Comment: If you do not observe the date at which the tags were lost, it is difficult to draw strong conclusions from this data. Is the failure rate measured in terms of the number of tags working in 2017?

Comment: @dv_bn That is my opinion too, and I am seeking some expert confirmation that this data does not indicate a clear connection. The Scottish Gamekeepers Association linked to this blog describing it as a "Scientist's Perspective". https://www.facebook.com/SGAgamekeepers/posts/1747794225283611 If you want more data on dates and tag reliability, it's in section 6 of the full report (link in comment above). Tags have a median life just below 3 years, but the median life goes up if you take "disappeared" tags out of the analysis.

Comment: @gung I took the time data out because it looks like everyone is trying to answer a question that I'm not asking. I look at the "stopped no malfunction" data, I see a variation with tag type, but I don't think there's enough variation to conclude that the report is poor because they didn't delve deeper into the variation shown here.

Comment: @dv_bn on failure rate. I am interested in your analysis only of the "stopped no malfunction" data. Is there a significant variation by tag type? I believe the cut off date was 2016. So some of the tags that are logged as still working may end up stopped no malfunction, but the bias is then in the favour of the persecutors

Comment: This really bothers me. Where the heck are these eagles disappearing into?!

Comment: @Aksakal There is a correlation with moors managed for driven grouse shooting https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/uk-scotland-40108063

Comment: To your question: "Can the statement be backed up?" I would answer yes, it can. However, the relationship is not causal, there are obvious confounding factors such as the age of the devices that cannot be controlled for. To any statement "it is obvious to see such and such causal relation", one does not need to reply with a proper causal inference showing the opposite conclusion. One must simply find a confounding variable which threatens the identification of this causal relation. Now, if your objective is to conduct proper causal inference, that is a different story.

Comment: @dv_bn agreed. I've been back to the report and found that when the authors of the report looked at reliability of tags they concentrated on the modern, most reliable 70GPS/GSM tags and ignored the 80NS model that had been used early in the trials. So I think the "scientist" that made the statement was trying to make a causal inference that had been eliminated in the analysis anyway.

Comment: @dv_bn they compared USA data for ‘stopped no malfunction’ tags and found a rate of c2%, the comparable rate for Scotland was about 25 times higher.For definitely identified malfunctions both countries had a similar rate (c2%)
They also looked at how long those tags survived. They found that all but one had a survival period that was less than the median for all tags. 
Also, 67% of US tags lasted longer than the expected 3y, whereas only 3% of Scottish tags lasted 3y.
They concluded that there was little chance that the Scottish tags may have actually malfunctioned..

Comment: Some background to the "scientist" that the Scottish Gamekeepers Association linked to: https://raptorpersecutionscotland.wordpress.com/2018/03/26/laughable-critique-of-golden-eagle-satellite-tag-review/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get to my answer from this comment "[look up the hypergeometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099867)" on math.stackexchange:

From Wikipedia's entry on [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

> In probability theory and statistics, the hypergeometric distribution
>   is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability
>   of k successes (random draws for which the object drawn has a
>   specified feature) in n draws, without replacement.

Then, using an online [Hypergeometric Calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx) and the following figures:

Population: 135

Number of successes in population: 42

Sample size: 17

Number of successes in sample: 8

I find that the probability of getting exactly 8 is 0.0703, and the probability of getting 8 or more is 0.1095

I think the "8 or more" figure is the relevant one in this case, and I have to say that this probability is lower than my intuition predicted.

So the numbers suggest that there is an 89% probability that there is something different about the failure rate when segregated by tag type. That does not mean that the cause of the difference *is* the tag type.

Comment: This doesn't control for the age of the tags, creating some doubt concerning the meaning or usefulness of the probability.

Comment: @whuber we have a "scientist" claiming that "certain tags have much higher percentage losses (80NS at 47%) [...] if we go by tag it implies that there could be tags and harnesses more prone to unknown failure than the rest" so the first thing I wanted to know was what the probability of getting 47% failure rate if we assumed that all the tags had the same failure rate.

Comment: @whuber Actually, the argument is probably moot because if you read the original report, the 80NS is largely ignored in the discussion on tag reliability and the case for stating that "stopped no malfunction" results are largely due to persecution is based mostly on the evidence from the 70GPS/GSM tags. The 80NS model was only deployed in the early years, is stated to be less reliable, and used a harness design more likely to be dropped prematurely.